# JQuery find first parent element with specific class prefix

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get the first parent which has a specific class prefix, suppose:

```
<div class="div-a3332"> 
  <div class="div-a89892">
    <p>
      <div class="div-b2">
        <div id="divid">hi</div>
      </div>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For example, my current element is `#divid` and I want to find the first element that has the class prefix div-a. So basically it will select:

```
<div class="div-a89892">
```

Comment: Stop. Use multiple classes, instead of combining information into once class. The 'matching' selector is slow, and this design doesn't scale for any modification. `<div class='a'>`, then provide rules for `div.a`. I don't know why you're putting `div` in the classname at all, actually.

Comment: Still, don't merge data into class-prefixes. This is a terrible pattern, and it's easily remedied with multiple classes.

Comment: @StefanKendall: Sometimes you're dealing with others' third-party crap, and sometimes you're supporting legacy apps you can't quickly fix.  Bad design is a fact of life, and this is a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) with a selector:

```
var $div = $('#divid').closest('div[class^="div-a"]');
```

Comment: BTW, no idea why this was downvoted. The class-prefix selector is brittle, but it _will_ work.

Comment: To OP: Make sure the element you're looking for is a parent somewhere up the DOM tree and not a sibling or similar to the object you are looking for (per the documentation). It's not "closest anywhere in the document" but "closest by working up the DOM tree".

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Also, I want to find the first element that has  specific prefix, that doesn't have to be a div element.

Comment: @Time then remove the `div` element selector: `$('#divid').closest('[class^="div-a"]')`. As @Stefan commented, though, you should really be using multiple classes.

Comment: This selector takes an absurd amount of cycles (but it still can be fast). If you need to support IE6,IE7, or IE8, this can really screw you if your DOM grows too large; IE throws up the "script is not responding" dialog when a certain number of JS VM instructions are executed, and NOT after a certain amount of time. I've seen scripts which complete in 0.1ms crash internet explorer for this very reason.

Comment: So you'll wind up trampolining this selection, or you could just fix the root design problem before-hand. @Matt Ball: You're telling a guy on a bridge to jump.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta as far as I can tell, the semantics of `.closest()` and `.parents()` have not changed in any way since I posted this answer.

Comment: be careful because 'closest' will also match the current element, potentially. You may needs parents(...).first()

Answer (score 60):

Jquery later allowed you to to find the parents with the [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method.

Hence I recommend using:

```
var $div = $('#divid').parents('div[class^="div-a"]');
```

This gives all parent nodes matching the selector. To get the first parent matching the selector use:

```
var $div = $('#divid').parents('div[class^="div-a"]').eq(0);
```

For other such DOM traversal queries, check out the documentation on [traversing the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: The answer is not misleading, its just showcasing another alternative to .closest(), .parents() looks more readable and is another solution the the problem.

Comment: Closest is a better solution than this as closest will just find the first match, whereas parents will find ALL matches going up the DOM.
Obviously more efficient to use closest, although I agree, it's not the best named function.

Comment: Funny enough, I ended up using this solution as .parentsUtil() wasn't working as i expected.