# Add class to closest parents child

Tags: jquery

Im trying to do something similar to this, but cant get it going.

[EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457618/jquery-find-first-parent-element-with-specific-class-prefix)

What I want to do different is to search for a class similar to the example, but then add a class to the sub "a" tag. Something like this.

```
$("#tabAdm").closest('li[class^="tabAdmission"] > a').addClass('active_pat_tab');
```

It seemed simple, but like I said, cant get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) will give you the desired ancestor reference, then you need to use a descendant traversal method to find the desired child

Use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children)

```
var xxx = $("#tabAdm").closest('li[class^="tabAdmission"]').children('a').addClass('active_pat_tab');
```

or if `a` is not a child of the `tabAdmission` instead a descendant - [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)

```
var xxx = $("#tabAdm").closest('li[class^="tabAdmission"]').find('a').addClass('active_pat_tab');
```